# Can't validate all the files that I upload

Tags: angular, mime-types, image-upload

well I am learning how to build a mean stack app, and am trying to do a ecommerce type app. My problem is related to image uploading.

I am trying to upload multiple files at once, but I get an error always, 
that comes from my mime type validation.

mime.type.validation.ts:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Observer, of } from 'rxjs';

export const mimeType = (

  control: AbstractControl
): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> => {
  if (typeof(control.value) === 'string') {
    return of(null);
  }
  const file = control.value as File;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  const frObs = Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<{ [key: string]: any }>) => {
      fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
       let result1: any;
       let finalResult: any;
       result1 = fileReader.result;
       finalResult = result1 as ArrayBuffer;

        const arr = new Uint8Array(finalResult).subarray(0, 4);
        let header = '';
        let isValid = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          header += arr[i].toString(16);
        }
        switch (header) {
          case '89504e47':
            isValid = true;
            break;
          case 'ffd8ffe0':
          case 'ffd8ffe1':
          case 'ffd8ffe2':
          case 'ffd8ffe3':
          case 'ffd8ffe8':
            isValid = true;
            break;
          default:
            isValid = false; // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
            break;
        }
        if (isValid) {
          observer.next(null);
        } else {
          observer.next({ invalidMimeType: true });
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
  );

  return frObs;
};
```

post-create.ts

```
onImagePick(event) {
let file =(event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
 let fileArray = Array.from(file);

 if(file === undefined){return;}
  this.form.patchValue({'image' : file});
  this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();    
  for(let fil of fileArray) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {   
  this.imagePreview.push(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(fil);    
  }      
}
```

error that it gives is:

ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

I believe the control of the mimetype is acting before I transform the FileList in a single File. So whenever it reaches the readAsArrayBuffer it is passing an argument of FileList instead of file. But am failing to discover how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the FileList there! So I put it inside the for, and it stopped the error.

```
 onImagePick(event) {
 let file =(event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
 let fileArray = Array.from(file);

 if(file === undefined){return;}
  for(let fil of fileArray) {
  this.form.patchValue({'image' : fil});
  this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();    
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {   
  this.imagePreview.push(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(fil);    
  }      
}
```